# What is the best way to handle iOS apps with auth token returning from suspended state?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle authorization tokens in response from an app coming back from a suspended state.

Within my app delegate I have an http request to validate the authorization token that is stored in the keychain.  This occurs when the app becomes active.  If status code is 401 (token not valid), user is taken to the main login screen.  This works well and has no issues.

I am running into trouble when the token is still valid (status code 200).  The problem is that since the app is returning from a suspended state, it automatically launches to the login screen (initial view controller) and not the screen the user closed the app from.  From the app delegate I have tried to move to a new view controller by setting it as the root view controller.  Although this works, the navigation bar isn't loaded.

Is there another way to handle apps in which returning from the suspended state should allow the user to continue?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing almost everything right, as I can conclude from

> Although this works, the navigation bar isn't loaded.

Just create a `UINavigationController` instance that would load a view from Storyboard.

I usually do it like this:

```
let storyboardID = LocalAuthWorker.cityInitiallySelected() ? MainStoryboardID.Main : ListsStoryboardID.Lists
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
window!.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:  UIStoryboard(name: storyboardID, bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController())
window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this just loads the navigationController on top of the login screen.  Because I am using the same method to load the tableViewController where I was to direct my users, it won't also load the navigationController.

Comment: I also just tried performing a segue from the login page to another page (the next page in the usual UX) but got the error `receivier ...loginPageViewController.... has no segue with identifier 'loginToLocation' ` which it does.

Comment: You should use the storyboard ID of the view controller wrapped into the programmatically created Nav Controller. It should work

Comment: Can you expand on the first line of code in your answer?  I'm not following that.